# swift json nested parsing

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to parse json and store it in a object but 'Availability' doesn't store anything. Maybe the struct is created wrong? It seems right since it's a array. Maybe there is a library I use? I can store the first struct Article but ArticleOne is always empty.I have to add more comments since stack thinks my post is mostly code.

Comment: What error do you get? Hint: Only values in double quotes are `String`. And specify CodingKeys to map the uppercased keys to lowercased struct members.

Comment: Availability is always empty.

Comment: Catch the `error` in a `do - catch` block. It tells you exactly what's wrong. Or check the types. There are many, many mismatchs.

Comment: Thank you vadian. This is the error I get. typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "Availability", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "IsThisTimeSlotActive", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: **Read** the error,  *CodingKey `IsThisTimeSlotActive` ... Expected to decode String but found a number instead* is pretty clear. Once again, ***Only values in double quotes are `String`***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties of the struct you are using - `ArticleOne` - has to be adjusted to the values in the json:

```
struct ArticleOne: Codable {
    let DemoVehicleAvailabilityId: Int
    let DemoVehicleId: Int
    let AvailabilityDateTime: String
    let IsOnHold: Bool
    let IsBooked: Bool
    let BookedDateTime: String
    let BookedBy: String?
    let IsAvailableForDemo: Bool
    let RiderReferenceId: Int
    let IsCheckedIn: Bool
    let CheckinDateTime: String
    let HoldUntill: String
    let UpdatedDT: String
    let ReservedByName: String?
    let ReservedByEmail: String?
    let ReservedByMobileNumber: String?
    let IsReservationConfirmed: Bool
    let ReservationConfirmDateTime: String
    let IsThisTimeSlotActive: Bool
    let History: [T]
}
```

`T` is the type of the elements in `History`.

Comment: `ArticleOne` has to be updated, I'll add the needed corrections shortly

Comment: @user1707694 I've updated the answer. You'll have to adjust the type `History`